# Having some difficulties with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match the string `X=10 Y=2 W=30 H=40` using the regex `([x|y|w|h|X|Y|W|H]=\d+)\s` however it doesn's match the whole string. I need it to match only the format above and nothing else. This `X=10,Y=2,W=30,H=40` and `X=10Y=2W=30H=40` should not compile as a valid string.

I changed it to `([XYWH]=[0-9]+\s)` but since the last group `H=40` does not contain a whitespace, it doesn't match it.

Comment: Something like https://ideone.com/c2ZF49? Validate the string first, then split. Else, return no match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match `X=10 Y=2 W=30 H=40` you could match the first 3 parts `X=10 Y=2 W=30` with `(?:[xywh]=\d+ )` which includes the whitespace at the end and repeat that 3 times `{3}`.

To match the last part without the whitespace you can use `[xywh]=\d+`. To get your exact match you could use anchors to assert the begin `^` and the end `$` of the line.

To match lower and uppercase characters for `[xywh]` you could use the case insensitive flag `i`. In Python you could enable this with `re.I` or `re.IGNORECASE`:

`pattern = re.compile('^(?:[xywh]=\d+ ){3}[xywh]=\d+$', re.IGNORECASE)`

[`^(?:[xywh]=\d+ ){3}[xywh]=\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/dq98eH/1/)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert postion at the start of the line
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[xywh]=\d+` [Character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which will match `x`, `y` `w` or `h` followed by `=` and one or more digits `\d+` followed by a whitespace.
- `){3}` Close non capturing group and repeat 3 times.
- `[xywh]=\d+` Character class which will match `x`, `y` `w` or `h` followed by `=` and one or more digits `\d+`
- `$` Assert the end of the line

[Demo Python](http://rextester.com/GAUK46868)

Comment: Is the ‘?:’ The ‘i’ flag that you mentioned?

Comment: @KleberSilva I have updated my answer and added a explanation and a demo.

Comment: Hey I really appreciate that! I’m trying to shorten it though to where I don’t need to repeat the expression just to match the white space that might or might not be there.

Comment: No, I’m trying to come up with a solution for that white space but I don’t want to have “[xywg]=\d+” twice in the expression, you know?

Comment: @KleberSilva Is there a reason you don't want to have that twice in your expression?

Comment: Not really, I just like to keep my code as clean as possible.

Comment: @KleberSilva I think you are not cluttering your code by using a regex that matches the pattern of your example data.

Comment: I think you’re right. I can’t come up with something else that matches the last white space without repeating the expression. Thank you for your help and explanation! I’ll give it to you.

Answer (score 2):

```
([XxYyWwHh]=\d+ ?){4}
```

This requires exactly 4 matches, and prevents anything but a space being used as a delimiter between fields.  However, it also allows the end (H=) to end without that delimiter.
https://regex101.com/r/O87qlt/3/

And you can use this to capture the groups in any order.  (But the resultant capture *values* are always in X Y W H order):

```
(?:(?:X=(\d+)|Y=(\d+)|W=(\d+)|H=(\d+)) ?){4}
```

https://regex101.com/r/O87qlt/5

Comment: wasn't me. but, a question: why the negative lookahead?

Comment: @sweaver2112 - ah...yes...unnecessary.  If the space isn't there the next one won't match.